# Why isn't my form posting any data even though I've set the name property?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

So I'm trying to post a form with some data, but for some reason when clicking the button that POSTS the data, I'm not getting anything serversided, all the values are NULL.

As you can see it's a simple form that uses razor and I've set the name and the id properties of the elements I want to send

```
<table class="table table-hover mb-0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Version</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var _model in Model)
                                {

                                <tr>

                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Start", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post))
                                    {
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <td id="serverid" name="serverid">@Html.DisplayTextFor(x => _model.ServerID) @Html.HiddenFor(x => _model.ServerID)</td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => _model.ServerName) @Html.HiddenFor(x => _model.ServerName)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => _model.Version) @Html.HiddenFor(x => _model.Version)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button type="submit" asp-action="Start" asp-controller="Dashboard" class="btn btn-icon waves-effect waves-light btn-success" onclick="Start('@_model.ServerName')"> <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> </button>
                                        </td>
                                    </div>
                                    }
                                </tr>
                                }


                            </tbody>

                        </table>
```

And here is what the model looks like

```
public class ServerModel
{
    public string ServerID { get; set; }
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the action that's inside the controller

```
//The "model" parameter here exists, but all the properties are null when inspecting it
public async Task<IActionResult> Start(ServerModel model)
        {
            //Doing stuff here
        }
```

Why are all the properties inside the model null when inspecting them after posting? I'm putting a breakpoint to inspect it.

Comment: I would start by taking out the name attributes ie "name="serverid"" this might be causing your issue. What are you using them for?

Comment: I thought you had to specify the name attribute so that it could map the element values to the right properties, for instance.. Element with name "serverid" maps to the property "ServerID"

Comment: MVC will automatically bind these for you via @Html.HiddenFor

Comment: I removed my answer, I missed the HiddenFor() somehow. But please show all relevant code. Why do you use `@Html.HiddenFor(x => _model.ServerID)` and not `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ServerID)`?

Comment: There, I updated the html

Answer (score 0):

Change your submit button to -

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-icon waves-effect waves-light btn-success"> <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> </button>
```

As you are within the form element (generated by beginform) you dont need the additional attributes. Also not entirely sure what your intentions are with -

```
onclick="Start('@_model.ServerName')
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can remove the `onclick="Start('@_model.ServerName')"` of submit button since you are passing the data via Form Post , then modify below codes :

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => _model.ServerID)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => _model.ServerName)
```

To :

```
<input name="ServerID" type="hidden" value="@_model.ServerID">
<input name="ServerName"   type="hidden" value="@_model.ServerName">
```

So it will match name with model's property name during model binding .